# Comparing contents received at Socket with a String in UDP

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, udp, strcmp

I have developed a UDP Client Server Application. Now I want to check if the client sends a string "EXIT", the Server receives this string, compares it with "EXIT" string and the program exits. 
But in my case, the Server is not able to compare the received string with "EXIT" string. 
below is what I am coding:

**Client:**

```
char exitBuffer[]="EXIT";
if (sendto(socketIdentifier,exitBuffer,strlen(exitBuffer) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &connectedSocket, sizeof(connectedSocket)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**SERVER:**

```
if ((recv_len = recvfrom(socketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Now comparing the contents of receive Buffer
if (receiveBuffer == "EXIT")
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You should be doing a string comparision, e.g. strcmp() rather than '=='.

Comment: He shouldn't even be doing that unless he *knows* the null-terminator is included in the read-buffer as part of the transmitted data. If it is not, it most-assuredly will not compare correctly unless exactly four chars are read and the receive buffer is 0-prefilled.

Comment: @WhozCraig - absolutely correct, I was assuming the sender was using a null-terminated string in the data, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried memcmp and it did it :)
Now the comparison done on the Server side is as follows:

```
if(memcmp(receiveBuffer,"EXIT",5) == 0)
{
    //receiveBuffer is eqaul to "EXIT".
}
```

Comment: This will not work correctly if recv_len is **ever** larger then 5. It will begin reading from undefined memory passed the string literal in the read-only segment where "EXIT" is stored, and quite possibly fault your program. You should be comparing at most 5, ideally 4 bytes, and that only if recv_len is at least 4 bytes or larger.

Comment: But don't you think that in case of comparison with 4 bytes only, if the Client sends a message e.g "EXITaFTER5MInutes", the comparison will be true, and program will exit, though I only want to exit if the Client send "EXIT" message.

Comment: That is an issue of the data you're sending. In truth a length-preamble of the command, or a formal text syntax uniquely identifying the command tokens, is warranted. It is no mistake things like HTTP and FTP use all those seemingly innocuous cr/lf tails after their commands. As you just presented it, EXITSomethingElse is a problem, but only because you should be looking for EXIT followed by a well-defined terminator (which could even be the null terminator if you designed it that way).

Comment: @WhozCraig: You are Right. Thank you for the explanantion, I edited my Answer :)